# Issue with Error 1310 when installing an app on Windows 10

Tags: user-accounts, user-profiles

Windows 10
I've been having issues with a particular desktop app that I've never had before. The app is having issues writing to a folder in the Documents folder. After verifying ownership of the Documents folder I was still having issues. I decided after rebooting and still not resolving to update the app to 8.7 from 8.6.

Now when I try to install the 8.7 version I am getting:
[image]

I find it strange that he installer cannot write to c:\Users\Public\Documents[any folder] considering that it is owned by System and Everyone has full control.

I have also tried turning off Windows Defender and rebooting. Neither helped. It seems like permissions issues with the user folder. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** Forgot to mention that I also tried running the install as Administrator. Still didn't help.

**EDIT 2**

```
    Directory: C:\Users\Public\Documents\LTShared


Path      Owner               Access
----      -----               ------
Materials NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM ERIC-DESKTOP\erics Allow  FullControl...
```

Comment: Please provide the ACL for **"..\Public\Documents\LTShared\Materials\Covest\"**

Comment: @Ramhound - Path      Owner               Access
----      -----               ------
Materials NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM ERIC-DESKTOP\erics Allow  FullControl...

Comment: The reason for this error after additional research isn't a permission problem one due to the fact a process currently has the file question open.  You should use the appropriate tool to determine what process currently has the file open.  Have you tried to reboot your machine?

Comment: @Ramhound  - Thank you. Yes.As I stated above "I have also tried turning off Windows Defender and rebooting. Neither helped." I also tried rebooting and then running the installer as amdimistartor. What would the appropriate tool to determine what has the file open be?

Comment: Whatever tool you decide to use to see what processes have the file opened.  There might not be a process, the error is pretty generic, but one of the reasons for the error is indeed the file is already open by another process.

Comment: @Ramhound - Just checked with Process Explorer. Nothing is reported to have the folder and the file the installer is trying to write does not exist in the public folder yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being Windows Defender blocking assess to:

```
>%userprofile%\Documents\LTUser\
```

using Controlled Folder Access. I had to go in and whitelist the apps that I knew were friendly in:

> Windows Defender > Virus and Threat protection > Virus and threat protection settings > Manage controlled folder access > Allow an app through Controlled folder access